# Calculate height of iTextSharp PDF document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

How can I calculate the height of the PDF document when using iTextSharp?

---

I'm using iTextSharp to position various images on a PDF document using Absolute Position. However I've noticed `SetAbsolutePosition()` positions the `Y` parameter from the bottom, so I need to calculate the height to be able to do something like:

```
Y = PdfHeight - i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using the PageSize, like this...

```
int yPos = pdfDocument.PageSize.Height - i - elementHeight;
```

i = the position you would set Y if it was from the top of the page

elementHeight = the height of the element you are positioning (e.g. an image)