# How to Get PDF page width and Height?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf , and I want to get the width and Height for each page in pdf using iTextSharp?

given this is the pdf I want to work with

```
string source=@"D:\pdf\test.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
```

Comment: Maybe usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910881/itextsharp-what-is-the-height-of-a-regular-pdf-page-in-pixels and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480730/get-pdf-page-size-with-itextsharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768809/calculate-height-of-itextsharp-pdf-document

Answer (score 12):

Do you want the MediaBox?

```
Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(page);
```

Do you want the rotation?

```
int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(page);
```

Do you want the combination of both?

```
Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page);
```

Do you want the CropBox?

```
Rectangle cropbox = reader.GetCropBox(page);
```

Most of them return an object of type `Rectangle` that has methods such as `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get the width and the height of the page.
Other useful methods are `getLeft()` and `getRight()` as well as `getTop()` and `getBottom()`. These four methods return the `x` and `y` coordinates that define the boundaries of your page.

Where did I find most of this documentation?

In [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of iText in Action.